# Vertex Shader trouble

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm having trouble getting my vertex shader (1.20) to work. I'm rendering a simple white triangle, but when I load the vertex shader the triangle disappears.

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

to no avail. I'm really confused because my fragment shader *does* work. For example,

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(.5, .6, .3, 1);
}
```

will turn my triangle green. I can't spot anything wrong (and the shaders compile without errors), so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You should show the code you're using to compile and link your shaders and programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to copy color and texture information as well:

```
            gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
            gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

(and much more if you intend to emulate all of the behavior of the fixed function pipeline)

Comment: Thanks; that worked. But I don't quite understand why I need to set the color and texture coordinates. Do you mean to say that the color and other attributes aren't pushed through the pipeline automatically once I load a shader?

Comment: Right.  When you load a vertex shader you are completely replacing what was there in the fixed function pipeline.  For example, with your 1 line and my 2 lines you still don't have lighting or multitexturing.